# C# fetch all phone numbers from database columns and separate with comma and display in textbox

Tags: c#

phone numbers should be displayed in format 299099933,23344443,322233333

```
ArrayList phonearr = new ArrayList();
conn.Open(); 
MySqlCommand sda = new MySqlCommand("select * from members", conn);

MySqlDataReader dr = sda.ExecuteReader();

while(dr.Read())
{
txtsmsphoneno.Text =  string.Join(",", phonearr.Add(dr["Phone"].ToString()).ToString());
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? At first glance, it looks like your code does what you want.

Comment: only one phone number displays in textbox,want to display in this format 20332333,232334343,344455555,2424444444 any help will be appreciated thanx

Comment: Don't use `ArrayList`.  Instead using `List<T>`.  `ArrayList` is a left over from the days before generics.  Also you need to add the values to the list in the loop, then join the values after the loop,

Comment: doesn't phonearr.Add(dr["Phone"].ToString()) just return an index?  how are you getting any phone numbers at all?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Unfortunately, questions like these are [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) because they address mostly the business logic instead of isolated programming issues. In case you have issues with the implementation of your system, try split your problem into [minimal, complete, and verifiable questions about programming issues](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

You are passing each element of database value to `string.Join` separately, so only one value will be set. It is being replaced every loop iteration Instead do this

```
List<string> phonearr = new List<string>();
while(dr.Read())
{
    phonearr.Add(dr["Phone"].ToString());
}
```

and then

```
txtsmsphoneno.Text =  string.Join(",", phonearr);
```

I haven't tested it but this should work

NB: I changed your ArrayList to a normal List for simplicity, but with the right conversion it should work with ArrayList too

Answer (score 2):

You need to store all the phone numbers you read in a list.  then after you are done reading convert the list to an array and join the string together then set the text field.

```
List<String> phoneNumbers = new List<string>();

while (dr.Read())
{
    phoneNumbers.Add(dr["Phone"].ToString());
}
txtsmsphoneno.Text = string.Join(",", phoneNumbers.ToArray());
```